# Help taking the partial derivative of a smooth function $u(t,x)$ that has been rescaled to $v(t,x) = \overline{u}(\frac{1}{t}, \frac{x}{t})$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am attempting to differentiate a smooth rescaled function $u(t,x)$ which has been given by

$$v(t,x) = \overline{u}\left(\frac{1}{t}, \frac{x}{t}\right),$$

with respect to both $t$ and $x$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $t \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$.

Is this just direct application of the chain rule? Do the following  attempts make sense?:

$$\partial_t v = \partial_t \overline{u} = -\frac{1}{t^2}\partial_t\overline{u}$$

and

$$\partial_x v = \partial_x \overline{u} = \frac{1}{t}\partial_x\overline{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

Having set
$$
v(t,x)=u(f(t),g(t,x)),\qquad\text{with }f(t)=1/t\text{ and }g(t,x)=x/t
$$
we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{t}}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}+\sum_j\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_j}}\frac{\partial{g_j}}{\partial{t}}\\
=-\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\sum_j\frac{x_j}{t^2}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_j}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x_i}}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}+\sum_j\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_j}}\frac{\partial{g_j}}{\partial{x_i}}\\
=0+\sum_j\delta_{ij}\frac{x_j}{t}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_j}}=\frac{x_i}{t}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_i}}
$$
where $\partial{u}/\partial{t}$ and $\partial{u}/\partial{x_i}$ are everywhere evaluated in $(f(t),g(t,x))$

Comment: Thank you. This clears up my issue.

Comment: To ensure that I am going about things properly, suppose I wish to compute $\Delta v$, then the individual second partials yield $$\partial_{x_i}^2 v = \dfrac{1}{t} \partial_{x_i} u + \dfrac{(x_i)^2}{t^2} \partial_{x_i}^2 u,$$ correct? So then $$\Delta v = \sum_i \dfrac{1}{t} \partial_{x_i} u + \dfrac{(x_i)^2}{t^2} \partial_{x_i}^2 u,$$ which is $$\Delta v = \frac{1}{t} \nabla u + \frac{|x|^2}{t^2} \Delta u.$$

Comment: I believe the expression for $\partial_{x_i} v = \frac{1}{t} \partial _{x_i} u$, since $\partial_{x_i} g_i = \frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @user285282: it seems correct, but not the last expression, because $\sum_i\partial_{x_i}u\neq\nabla{u}$ and $\sum_i(x_i)^2\partial^2_{x_i}u\neq\sum_i(x_i)^2\sum_i\partial^2_{x_i}u$.

Comment: You are correct, my bad; however when considering the adjustment to the original partial in the spatial variable I believe the expression for the laplacian is just:

$$\Delta v = \frac{1}{t^2} \Delta u.$$